# What's wrong with the first element in HOF in JS?

Tags: javascript

Here I have a string with repeated chars,
I want to get the string without repetition, so I used map with specific index, but I don't know what's wrong with the 1st repeated char, when I used slice(i+1,1) all thing was good, but when I used slice(i,1) also all thing was good except the first repeated char.

The output of the 1st code is : elzero
The output of the 2nd code is : eelzero
What's the problem?

Here's the two codes:

```js
let myString = "EElllzzzzzzzeroo";

let elzero = myString
  .split("")
  .map(function(ele, i = 1, myString) {
    console.log(i);
    if (myString[i] === myString[i + 1]) {
      return myString[i + 1].slice(i + 1, 1);
    } else {
      return myString[i];
    }
  })
  .join("");

console.log(elzero);
// Elzero
```

And here's the second:

```js
let myString = "EElllzzzzzzzeroo";

let elzero = myString
  .split("")
  .map(function(ele, i = 1, myString) {
    console.log(i);
    if (myString[i] === myString[i + 1]) {
      return myString[i].slice(i, 1);
    } else {
      return myString[i];
    }
  })
  .join("");

console.log(elzero);
// EElzero
```

Comment: Just curious, why don't you just return empty string, without using slice? 

`if (myString[i] === myString[i + 1]) {
          return '';
}`

Answer (score 2):

Your first code block only works because your `.slice()` happens to be returning empty strings. You really don't need to use `.slice()` at all, since all it does is generate an empty string which is then removed when you use `.join()`. The `.slice()` call does NOT update/remove an element like `.splice()` on an array does.

In your second code block, you're doing:

```js
myString[i].slice(i, 1);
```

If `i` is `0` then you are on the first character in your string, so `myString[0]` is `"E"`. Here, `.slice(0, 1)` says, give me the string that starts at index `0` up to, but not including index `1`. This results in `"E"` being returned.

For all of your subsequent calls `myString[i]` gives you back one character (so it only has one index, `0`), but you're trying to use `.slice()` to get a portion of your string from indexes that don't exist as `i` is bigger than your index. Moreover, `i` is bigger than your second argument, so when `i` is 1, you're asking to get get the string portion from index 1 (which doesn't exist) up to but not including 1, which results in an empty string. When `i` is `2`, its a similar situation, which results in an empty string.

What you should be doing is removing the use of `.slice()` altogether, and instead return an empty string when you want to omit the character:

```js
let myString = "EElllzzzzzzzeroo";

let elzero = myString
  .split("")
  .map(function(ele, i, myString) {
    if (ele === myString[i + 1]) { // if current char (ele) equals the next char (myString[i+1]), then "remove" the current char by mapping it to an empty string (this is removed when we `.join("")`)
      return "";
    } else {
      return ele;
    }
  })
  .join("");

console.log(elzero); // Elzero
```

More concisely, you can rewrite this with arrow functions and a ternary like so. You can also use `Array.from()` to iterate the code points (ie: characters) within your string, and use the second argument as the mapping function:

```js
const myString = "EElllzzzzzzzeroo";
const elzero = Array.from(
  myString,
  (ele, i) => ele === myString[i + 1] ? "" : ele
).join("");
  
console.log(elzero); // Elzero
```

Alternatively, using a different approach, you can use `.replace()` with a regular expression to remove repeated characters:

```js
const myString = "EElllzzzzzzzeroo";
const elzero = myString.replace(/(.)\1*/g, '$1')
  
console.log(elzero); // Elzero
```

The `(.)` captures a character and groups it, the `\1*` is a backreference that matches zero or more of the grouped character repeated, and the `"$1"` replaces the matched characters with the singular grouped character.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning `myString[i]`, not `myString[i+1]`, you have to compare `myString[i]` with `myString[i-1]`:

```js
let myString = "EElllzzzzzzzeroo";

let elzero = myString
  .split("")
  .map(function(ele, i = 1, myString) {
    console.log(i);
    // if (myString[i] === myString[i + 1]) {
    if (myString[i-1] === myString[i]) {
      return myString[i].slice(i, 1);
    } else {
      return myString[i];
    }
  })
  .join("");

console.log(elzero);
// EElzero
```